# The Stack Exchange software should not be rejecting valid email addresses

Tags: bug, status-norepro

My chosen email address, which has worked for years at other Stack Exchange sites, was today rejected for a question at Physics Stack Exchange, and again here at the corresponding Meta.

In this case, the email address is `bignose+stackoverflow@whitetree.org`.

[RFC 3696](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3696) makes it plain that **any printable character is valid in an email address**, given the protocol rules. So, for example an email address containing a punctuation character (`:`, `+`, `@`, `~`, etc.) in the local part is valid so long as it follows the standard.

Indeed, in the local-part (the part before the final `@` character), *any* character may appear in a valid email address. It's not up to the sender to decide what is and isn't a valid local-part.

[Specifically](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3696#section-3):

```
Hence, they should not be rejected in filtering routines
but, should instead be passed to the email system for
evaluation by the destination host.
```

Please **ensure the Stack Exchange software does not reject valid email addresses** chosen by the user for their notification address.

Comment: are you referring to `name+extra@example.com`? That works fine. Maybe if you emailed us the exact string..

Answer (score 1):

Plus addressing works fine, and has since forever. I can't reproduce this.

(We use plus addresses all the time internally too, so if it wasn't working, we would know..)